# change the position of Ribbon Tabs to the right in SharePoint foundation 2010 Master Page

Tags: sharepoint, tabs, designer, ribbon

I want to change the position of Ribbon Tabs to the right in SharePoint foundation 2010 Master Page. 
But i am not able to find any Controls related to Tabs(like:Ribbon.Tab) in "v4.master" using SharePoint Designer 2010.
similar like below image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This [page](http://styledpoint.com/blog/ribbon-customization-changing-placement-look-and-behavior/) details the operation needed.

> Here is a breakdown of the essential controls laid out to better
>   understand how it all works:

```
1. <SPRibbon PlaceholderElementId=”RibbonContainer”>
2. <SharePoint:SPRibbonPeripheralContent Location=”TabRowLeft”>
3. <SharePoint:SiteActions>
4. <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id=”PlaceHolderGlobalNavigation”> <SharePoint:PopoutMenu ID=”GlobalBreadCrumbNavPopout”> <SharePoint:PageStateActionButton>
5. <SharePoint:SPRibbonPeripheralContent Location=”TabRowRight”>
```

Applying information from [here](http://sharepointexperience.com/csschart/csschart.html), the following seems to do the trick (add it to the master page)

```
<style>
.ms-cui-topBar2{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark2-Lighter")] */
 border-bottom:1px solid #cad2db;
height:43px;
float:right;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I have already rearrange each part one by one and if i remove every thing that <SPRibbon PlaceholderElementId=”RibbonContainer”>
contains it shows only Browse and Page Tabs similar ike the "Image"  ..............................................   <SharePoint:SPRibbon
   runat="server"
   PlaceholderElementId="RibbonContainer"
   CssClass="SPRibbon">
   
  </SharePoint:SPRibbon>

Comment: what's in your CSS for the SPRibbonPeripheralContent item ?

Comment: Add this to your master page, it seems to do the trick: <style>
.ms-cui-topBar2{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark2-Lighter")] */
 border-bottom:1px solid #cad2db;
height:43px;
float:right;
}
</style>